# how to add multiple images in single image.network()?

Tags: flutter, dart

so i want 3 different images on this code

```
body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Swiper(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Image.network(
                  "https://github.com/jzoom/images/raw/master/swiper-example.gif",
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                );
              },
              itemCount: 3,
              viewportFraction: 0.9,
              scale: 0.9,
            )),
      ),
```

i want 3 images within use of one method.

Comment: You can’t add multiple images inside one Image.network image. Do you have a list of urls to images you want to show?

Comment: yes, i can use any three just help me this , atleast just make a template that works with this code , i will fill the links by myself

Comment: Check out the answer from VivekChib.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a list of images (replace `""` with your URLs)

   `List<String> _images = ["","",""];`
2. Now make these changes in your swiper widget:

   2.1 `return Image.network(_images[index]);`

   2.1 `itemCount: _images.length`

Comment: return Image.network(_images[index]); what to add inside[index]

Comment: the index is from itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) leave it as it is.